# Speed acceleration using sum reduction is only 2X using 12 threads using OPENMP

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp

I have a code snippet which is a sum over a on dimensional array y[]. I want to accelerate it using `omp for`, and I create 12 thread on a 12 core node to execute this code snippet. When I test the time, it turn out that the time is only a half when I execute this part on single core(no parallel). Anyone please give me some instructions how I can speed this part up?

I have tried change the schedule to `guided`, but it doesn't work.

```
Da_re=Da_im=Db_re=Db_im=Na=Nb=0.0;
#pragma omp parallel shared(Da_re,Da_im,Db_re,Db_im,Na,Nb,y,Ns) private(sk)
{
#pragma omp for schedule(static) reduction(+:Da_re,Da_im,Db_re,Db_im,Na,Nb)
for(sk=0;sk<=16*(Ns-1);sk+=16) // the dimension for y[] is 16*Ns=16*803*803
    {
    Da_re += y[sk+0];   
    Da_im += y[sk+1];
    Db_re += y[sk+2];
    Db_im += y[sk+3];
    Na += y[sk+4]+y[sk+5];
    Nb += y[sk+6]+y[sk+7];
    }
}
```

Comment: What were the actual times? Just telling us it's help isn't helpful. Going from two minutes to one minutes is completely different from going from 100 milliseconds to 50 milliseconds.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz time passed is:3.461000 ms using 12 threads, while using one thread time passed is:7.489000 ms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7 milliseconds is *way* too small to be a meaningful measurement. It's like trying to tell how tell which of two maid cleans faster by sending them across town to clean a closet. All you're measuring is the overhead to get started working and then stop working, you're not measuring the actual time they work.

Comment: Then how can I decrease the time we going parallel? You are assuming that is part of program is not a ideal part to parallel? I am doing the evolution, this part will appear again and again so I really want to try to make it small. I suspect that the time can be small if I don't use the reduction and use some other method instead.

Comment: I'm saying this is too small a thing to usefully parallelize. It will take too long to assign the work and combine the results. You need to parallelize a larger chunk, or you won't get any benefit.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. Actually you are very right about this, when I get rid of this part(don't execute it), the total time of my program doesn't decrease in time.